# Photoshop: export each guide as individual image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, guides

Suppose I have this dummy project where I set guides on my workspace
[image]

How would I now export this in three different images?
I would like to have one image for each guide block such that

- The first image holds the text `Lorem ips` on the right
- The second image holds the text `m` on the left and `lore` on the right
- The third image holds `em ipsum` on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the *Slice Tool*.
- Click the *Slices From Guides* button in the top.
- Enter *File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)*.
- Select the wanted settings and click *Save*.
- In the save dialog, set *Slices* to *All Slices*.